# Complete separable metric space

Tags: general-topology

Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field of cardinality continuum containing the rationals.

Is there always a  (canonical if possible) way to equipp $K$ with a topology which makes it into a separable complete metric space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $K$ is an algebraically closed field of cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$ containing the rationals, then there is a field isomorphism between $K$ and $\Bbb C$.

Since $\Bbb C$ is a separable complete metric space, we can just transport the structure to $K$ via that isomorphism.

Comment: Yes, but is there a canonical, intrinsic way to do this? Because the isomorphism onto $\mathbb{C}$ is not canonical.

Comment: Define canonical. The isomorphism requires the axiom of choice in most cases. But once you fix that isomorphism, the rest is definable from it.

Comment: For instance such that $\mathbb{Q}^{alg}$ is dense in the topology in such a way that Cauchy sequences converge.

Comment: Note that any such isomorphism must preserve $\Bbb Q^{alg}$ (although not necessarily pointwise), and since it is dense in $\Bbb C$ it will be dense in the resulting topology on $K$.